# 2 column with images and add padding

Tags: html, css

```
#wrap img{
    width:50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

<div id="wrap">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
</div>
```

When I add padding to the images I have to set the width less than 50%, that will cause the padding not align. How to fix that problem?

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/7gon7kef/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try css column-count:

```css
#wrap { width:100%; -moz-column-count:2; -moz-column-gap:10px; -moz-column-width:50%; -webkit-column-count:2; -webkit-column-gap:10px; -webkit-column-width:50%; column-count:2; column-gap:10px; column-width:50%;}
#wrap img { width:100%; margin-bottom:5px;}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: I would stress that css columns are not supported in older versions of ie. IE9 for example!

Comment: Yes, Aaron you are right.
This is CSS3 property, that obviously doesn't support completely in older version of IE

Comment: You say **obviously**, but IE9 isn't that old and it supports 95% of other CSS3?

Comment: In your words "it supports 95% of other CSS3"
not 100%

Answer (score 2):

you will need to use `border-box` this should be used in all of your projects it'll help when you come to align elements using percentage widths.

`border-box` respects border, padding when it comes to sizing an element.

Generally I would apply this to an asterisk which would apply the style to every element on the page...

```
* {box-sizing: border-box}
```

If you're applying this to only your images then the snip below will help you.

```css
#wrap {
  background: grey;
}
#wrap img {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use html like this -

```css
#wrap{
   width: 250px;
    background:red;
    padding:8px 4px 1px
}

#wrap img{
    width:50%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0px 4px 4px;
    box-sizing:border-box
    
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/><!--
--><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/><!--
--><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/><!--
--><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/><!--
--><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/><!--
--><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
</div>
```

Or you can try `float:left` like this-

```css
.clearfix:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  }
#wrap{
  width: 250px;
  background:red;
  padding:5px;
}

#wrap img{
  width:50%;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  display:block;
  float:left;
  padding:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  

}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" class="clearfix">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
</div>
```

Comment: the padding is not even, the bottom padding is too much

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to align them in rows of 2 with padding try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/fo270Lzy/

Note i've used `overflow:hidden;` to clear the floats but you could also use the proper clearfix method instead.

`display:inline-block` adds additional space between elements.  You also need `box-sizing: border-box;` to make your width include the padding.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you if you don't required older browser support.
Basically in CSS3 "`box-sizing`" introduce for the same aim. It'll adjust  the box with your specified width.

Also I have used `font-size:0;` to wrapper to remove exptra space between images as we have used `display: inline-block`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ukdpshdc/1/)